# Fit rectangle into another polygon

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry

Given any polygon A defined by set of points on 2D plane I want to check if another polygon B (say convex or to make it simper- rectangle) fits into first one meaning all points and edges from B belong to inside of A.
First solution coming to my mind is to draw A then move B one by one point on x and y axis and then check using mask.
But maybe there's another more elegant and efficient solution.

Comment: find four most extreme points of polygon B ... then check those

Comment: A can be non-covex so it may not work. Also holes in A ruin this approach

Comment: I remember such a question from several months past. lots of interesting approaches. -- if you don't need to *fit*, but only test _whether_ it's fully contained, that's a simple boolean operation (if you have masks)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz do you have a link by any chance? Tried to search for similar question but found nothing.

Comment: Also my problem with masking is that it assumes finite resolution. I wonder if there solution applicable to continuous space

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I finally went with rolling window over image and masking solution. Not most efficient solution but works...

Answer (score 0):

Check that any vertex of B lies inside A, for example, using [PnPoly algorithm](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html)

Check for intersection of B edges with A edges (simple if B is rectangle - just use any [line-clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping))

---

For complex polygons it is worth to apply some geometric library ([Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) has some Python interface, but I think more libraries do exist -  Shapely  etc)